# ISO 8601 hour number inconsistency

Tags: time, iso8601

ISO 8601, section 5.3 specifies

> hours are represented by two digits from [01] to [24]

But below, section 5.3.2 permits both "00:00:00" and "24:00:00" for midnight.

I also know from experience that the midnight hour is commonly represented by the digits [00], and never by [24] except at the exact second of midnight. So this appears to be an error in the specification. Surely someone has noticed this before me. Is there published errata? Am I missing something?

Comment: You are probably looking at an old version of the standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know a section 5.3 in latest ISO-8601-paper, but see this:

> 4.2.3 Midnight
>
> The complete representations in basic and extended format for midnight, in accordance with 4.2.2, shall be expressed in
>   either of the two following ways:
>
> ```
>     Basic format       Extended format 
>  a) 000000             00:00:00 (the beginning of a calendar day) 
>  b) 240000             24:00:00 (the end of a calendar day)
> ```
>
> The representations may have reduced
>   accuracy in accordance with 4.2.2.3 or may be designated as a time
>   expression in accordance with 4.2.2.5. To represent midnight the
>   representations may be expanded with a decimal fraction containing
>   only zeros in accordance with 4.2.2.4.
>
> NOTE 1 Midnight will normally be represented as [00:00] or [24:00].
>
> NOTE 2 The end of one calendar day [24:00] coincides with [00:00] at the start of the next calendar
>   day, e.g. [24:00] on 12 April 1985 is the same as [00:00] on 13 April
>   1985. If there is no association with a date or a time interval both a) and b) represent the same local time in the 24-hour timekeeping
>   system.
>
> NOTE 3 The choice of representation a) or b) will depend upon
>   any association with a date, or a time interval. Representations where
>   [hh] has the value [24] are only preferred to represent the end of a time interval in accordance with 4.4 or recurring time interval in accordance with 4.5.

So I think **all is fine, no inconsistency.**

By the way, I have adapted this special value 24:00 in my Java time library Time4J (see class `net.time4j.PlainTime`) to enable more elegant time interval descriptions. And I also know from real life that such a hour value is not unusual (for example in shop opening times).